# How to logout from IdentityServer on a Win Form app without displaying a Browser

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I'm trying to log out from an IdentityServer via the OidcClient libraries, but the solution that I have now requires me to have an empty dialog that pops up for 5 seconds before being able to log out. This is very ugly and there must be a better way to do it.

In the [official example](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/blob/master/WinFormsWebView/WebView/WinFormsWebView.cs) for preventing the form to pop up the event "BeforeNavigate2" is used, but that's not available without including some COM imports and extending the WebBrowser control as shown [here](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/blob/master/WinFormsWebView/WebView/ExtendedWebBrowser.cs) and that's something I'm trying to avoid as well.

I already tried to replace the ShowDialog with a semaphore, but if I wait on it I will get a deadlock because the waiting thread is the same that is supposed to fire the "Navigated" event.
I also tried to replace the navigate of the browser with an HttpClient but than I lose the functionality of the redirects and the cookies deletion that the WebBrowser already handle

This is my code:

```
public override Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options) {
    BrowserResult result = null;
    var t = new Thread(() => result = Run());
    //needed because the browser UserControl will throw an exception if not inside a STA thread
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
    t.Join();
    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(result);
}
private BrowserResult Run(){
    form = new Form { Name = "WebAuthentication", Text = formCaption, Width = 
    formWidth, Height = formHeight, ShowIcon = false };
    browser = new WebBrowser { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    form.Controls.Add(browser);
    browser.Navigated += (sender, args) => {
                         form.Close();
                       };
    browser.Navigate(options.StartUrl);
    form.ShowDialog();
    return new BrowserResult { ResultType = BrowserResultType.Success };
}
```

What I'm doing here is to use the ShowDialog to block the execution until the web request is fullfilled withoud blocking the thread and then releasing it with the form.Close().

Ideally, the log out would take not more than a couple of seconds and no windows should pop up.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: don't have an answer, just an idea: why not to try another web browser control, such as https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/ that might be simper than playing with embedded into Windows magic